# An equation in sine and tan

Tags: trigonometry, classical-mechanics

So I had this mechanics problem[image] and it was pretty straight forward until I reached two final equations, if any of them can be solved, the problem is solved.

One of the equations is a fourth degree equation in terms of the normal contact force on the disc, and it can’t even be treated as a quadratic, so pretty hopeless.

The other one, which, as I later saw, was used in the model answer to get the angle theta was $ 880\sin{\theta} = 400\tan{\theta} +20(9.81) $.
Now I had tried to play with sines, cosines, tangents, trig identities but for the life of me I cannot think of a way after all that except maybe using a taylor polynomial of second or third degree or using a recursive formula to approximate the roots, but because what was written in the model answer was this equation followed by “solving for theta we get $27.1$ degrees and $50.2$ degrees” I feel that this equation has an exact solution which is beyond me. Could anybody please clarify the way to solve such an equation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can only say that I get the impression that these are numerical solutions.

Comment: Good people, I swear to God I’m not an obnoxious person who thinks they’re entitled to help.. I tried to put a Hello there multiple times at the beginning of the question but the editor just wouldn’t accept it :’D

Comment: Here's a [graph](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=graph+88*sin(x)-40*tan(x)-19.62,+0%3Cx%3C2*pi)

Comment: $880 \sin \theta=400\tan \theta+20g \implies 44\sin \theta =20\dfrac {\sin \theta}{\cos \theta}+g \implies 22\sin 2\theta = 20\sin \theta+g\cos \theta \implies 22\sin 2\theta=\sqrt {20^2+g^2} \cdot \sin \left(\theta +\arctan \dfrac g{20}\right)$ unless I am wrong. Does this help?

Comment: Also for the quartic: https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Ferrari_method

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan well, thanks, but I thought of this and still, how can one reach a value for theta from this point? Is there a way to solve an equation of the form $a sin(x) + b sin(y) = 0$?

Comment: @user401445 Indeed there is! https://www.intmath.com/analytic-trigonometry/6-express-sin-sum-angles.php is an example of R formula. This should do it for you, as I used this to go from $20 \sin \theta +g\cos \theta$ to $\sqrt {20^2+g^2} \cdot \sin \left( \theta +\arctan \dfrac g{20}\right)$